# when do we need to call prevent default in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i attach a event listener on click event, to few list items. in my function click_handler below, before i do anything , i call e.preventDefault(). but i'm not sure if i need this here. i understand that this call prevents any default action, but i'm still not sure when do we need it or not. in this case, when these items are clicked, i do want to open the urls associated with it in a new tab, and also do pass some data to google analytics script.

html

```
<ul>
  <li><a class='linkitems' href="..."></a></li>
  <li><a class='linkitems' href="..."></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

js file

```
document.getElementsByClassName("linkitems").addEventListener("click", click_handler);

function click_handler(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   //pass link data for google analytics
}
```

Comment: If there's a link associated to it, you should probably use an `<a>` element.

Comment: You can ask yourself this question "What is the default behaviour when I click on a `li` element ?"

Comment: @tadman `preventDefault`  doesn't prevent event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

if it's somthing which refresh the all page and you want to prevent it's.
like when you press a submit button on a form it's refresh and rerender the all page so with preventDefault you prevent this default

Comment: thanks .  in my page i don't have submit or any other controls which would submit the page. that is what i wanted to know,would i need prevent default in such case

Comment: Hi Hillel, welcome and nice to see your first comment. This is however, more of a comment than solution. I know you cannot comment as of yet, but just as a general information for you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the function `e.preventDefault()` is used to avoid the standard behavior of a tag (an associated default behavior, for example on text input, on link `<a>`, etc.

In your case it is useless because you don't have a submit button or some event associated with the `<li>` tags by default.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp